# nodejs swig and css ignored

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a problem.
I am developing an application generated with express -generator I have in my public folder / stylesheets my css file ( style.css )
It is loaded in the page but not taken into account here is the code include :

**/views/layout.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Express.js</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Démo Express.js</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                {% include './include/nav.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**/views/include/nav.html**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**/views/contact.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<section class="container">
    {% if name %}
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <strong>Well done!</strong> thank you for your <b>{{name}}</b> sends
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form role="form" action="/contact" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="msg">Message</label>
            <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" id="msg" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

and url :  : http://vps204433.ovh.net:3000/contact

i follow this tutorial : http://webiose.com/2014/04/express-js-le-micro-framework-pour-node-js/#comment-14

An idea ?
Thank you

Comment: I cannot see any reference to style.css in your code

Comment: Here => <link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> this code is the code of tutorial but my code is identique <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Look source of http://vps204433.ovh.net:3000/contact